# SQL Server Dynamic Pivot Column Names

Tags: sql-server, pivot-table

For the necessity of my application, I must return the column names of a query as the very first row.
Now I must PIVOT this result in order to UNION it with my result set, but the difficult part is: it must be dynamic, so if I ever add new columns to this table, the SELECT will bring all the names pivoted.

The following SELECT brings me the Column names:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Codes'
ORDER BY INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.ORDINAL_POSITION
```

And my result set is:

```
COLUMN_NAME
Id
CodeName
Country
StartDate
EndDate
```

What I expect is:

```
Id    CodeName    Country    StartDate    EndDate (... whatever other columns I might have)
```

Is there any easy way to do that without hardcoding the column names?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query#10404455 you can use `stuff` part from this

Comment: The expected result should have a separate column name for each 'COLUMN_NAME'. What is the preferred naming scheme?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + COLUMN_NAME + ']', 
               '[' + COLUMN_NAME + ']')
               FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME,INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.ORDINAL_POSITION O 
               FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
               WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'CODES') PV  
               ORDER BY O


DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = '           
              SELECT TOP 0 * FROM 
             (
                 SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                 WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''CODES''
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 MIN(COLUMN_NAME)
                 FOR [COLUMN_NAME] IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p    

            '     
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

Comment: Cool no need of promises here

Comment: yep it is working now. First time you were missing commas between columns

Comment: I think this should be what the OP requested. Good answer.

Comment: Thank you. Fell free to ask for any clarifications dude :) @user3472897

Answer (score 3):

Starting with SQL Server 2017, there's a function for this: STRING_AGG.
I used the QUOTENAME function as well here, to make adding the [ ] brackets easier.

```
DECLARE @ColumnNames NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @ColumnNames = STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME), ',')
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME='Codes';
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way would be by `declaring a variable` and assigning the columns with `comma separted`. Try this.

```
DECLARE @col_list VARCHAR(max)=''

SELECT @col_list += '['+ COLUMN_NAME + '],'
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'Codes'
ORDER  BY INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.ORDINAL_POSITION

SELECT @col_list = LEFT(@col_list, Len(@col_list) - 1)

SELECT @col_list
```

Comment: I think the OP wants a result set where each column name is contained in a *separate column*.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos i Didn't get you OP wants to get the column list that can be used in pivot to generate columns dynamically. Run the above query in your DB and check

Comment: OK I had a different interpretation of the OP. As a side note I did not downvote your answeer.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos - No thats cool. Just want to clarify with you