# SQL Pivot Table from dynamic columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

I wrote this query to generate **pivot table**  :

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        ItemName_AR as [ItemName], 
        NetValue as Amount 
    FROM view_WH_CompanyTransactionDtl
) as s
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Amount)
    FOR [ItemName] IN (select ItemName_AR from WH_Items)
)AS pvt
```

but  it cuases the following error in

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.

at this statment

```
FOR [ItemName] IN (select ItemName_AR from WH_Items)
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you may not use a select statement to provide the variety of values (unpivoted form)=columns(pivoted form). You may either use 
`IN ([value1],[value2])` etc
or consider a dynamic solution, here's a link:
[SQL Server Dynamic Pivot Column Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27602733/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-column-names)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create Dynamic SQL PIVOT like that. You may try something like this...

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(max) = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + Quotename(ItemName_AR)
         FROM   WH_Items       
         FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''); 

DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(max) =  'SELECT *
                                    FROM (
                                        SELECT 
                                            ItemName_AR as [ItemName], 
                                            NetValue as Amount 
                                        FROM view_WH_CompanyTransactionDtl
                                    ) as s
                                    PIVOT
                                    (
                                        SUM(Amount)
                                        FOR [ItemName] IN ('+ @cols +')
                                    )AS pvt';

EXECUTE(@query)
```